# Vim: underscore(_) automatically converted to (<-)

Tags: r, vim, settings

I have been writing R scripts in Vim for some time now. Starting an hour ago, I began facing an issue that every time I type an underscore (`_`), it gets automatically converted to `<-`.

What setting did I change for this to happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:verbose imap _` should tell you which (probably filetype plugin) has set this.

It's less likely to be an abbreviation, but `:verbose ia _` would tell you.

Comment: And in case you don't know your history, `_` used to be the assignment operator in S (and then R). So `x_5` was like `x<-5`, and so emacs' ESS and Vim's R plugin implement this replacement to help us old timers and annoy the hadley_fan_bois :)

Answer (score 6):

The VIM: r-plugin does indeed change the mapping but the documentation section 4.1 states "it is possible to insert an actual underscore into your file by typing a second underscore".

Thus, while you can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453482/disable-underscore-shortcut-inserting-in-vim-r-plugin) the conversion of _ to <- it is easy to override temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

It may be also worthwhile to add that a convenient setting may involve re-assigning the operator, for instance the `.vimrc` setting:

```
" Nvim-R extra settings
"" Change assignment operator
let R_assign_map = "|"
```

Would assign the [r](/questions/tagged/r) assignment operator **`<-`** to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>. This feature is [described ithe provided documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/master/doc/Nvim-R.txt). In the `R_assign` section.

Answer (score 1):

To add more options to what you can do, Nvim-R has not only R_assign_map as [@konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219139/5900241) pointed out, but `R_assign` which manages how the feature works. A previous answer on duplicate answer mentioned an outdated version of R_assign (older name) being set to 0 as the answer.

I have found that the actual way to use this variable as of at least this post date (while the variable is still called `R_assign`) that there are 2 valid values thus 3 functions. I have only tried values of -1 to 3, but I found 1 and 2 to produce something, so here they are:

- Invalid values (`let R_assign=-1` (anything but 1 and 2)) made it so that _ produced <- and any subsequent _ keys produced more <-
- `let R_assign=1` produced the default documented behaviour of 1 _ makes a <- and the next _ makes (thus two _) a single _
- `let R_assign=2` flips it so that a single _ makes _ and another _ makes a <- (so two _ for a <-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `~/.vimrc`:

```
let R_assign = 0
```

Close and reopen nvim and `_` will work as expected.

Source: [here](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/issues/95#issuecomment-603389168).