# Disable underscore "_" shortcut inserting "<-" in Vim R plugin

Tags: r, vim, vim-plugin, vim-r

By default, the Vim-R-plugin inserts `<-` whenever I type or paste an underscore `_`. This creates problems when I paste stuff like `geom_bar`, which becomes `geom <- bar`. Is there a way to turn this short-cut off?

I tried looking at the [manual](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html#r-plugin-use) (scroll down to Edit section) but couldn't figure out how to do it.

I'm using Vim-R-plugin Version 0.9.9.9
for Vim version 7.4.

Comment: @csgillespie, I agree.  The answer given here may be more helpful than the one from a week ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the help page of the plugin:

> 6.3. Assignment operator and Rnoweb completion of code block
>
> ...
>
> To completely disable this feature, put in your vimrc:
>
> let vimrplugin_assign = 0

--

EDIT: As of writing this (2019-10-25), add this to your vimrc instead:

> 6.4. Assignment operator and Rnoweb completion of code block
>
> ...
>
> let R_assign = 0

Comment: you're a star! Thanks

Comment: @rcs:  I am not sure how SO works, but I think this question and your answer are going to disappear, since the question is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380926/vim-underscore-automatically-converted-to .  I think it would be a Good Thing if you repeated your answer there.

Comment: @benjifisher No *need* to duplicate the answer. Duplicates are not usually deleted and with the work of time, google will point to this answer that pleases most people. Actually for me that was the first google suggestion on my research