# disable underscore replacement in neovim r-plugin

Tags: neovim

In `vim`, this could be turned off as such: [Disable underscore "_" shortcut inserting "<-" in Vim R plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453482/disable-underscore-shortcut-inserting-in-vim-r-plugin)

What is the equivalent in `neovim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to `.nvimrc` did the trick:

```
let R_assign = 0
```